# SearchView could not find the searched word in ArrayList Kotlin

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I created an ArrayList that holds data from the Firebase Realtime Database. The problem is, the list checkbox data successfully appears with this then the ArrayList has been filled with data, but when using SearchView to search data it does not find anything (SearchView says ArrayList does not contain the data you are looking for), here is my code

```
databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("CF_DayaTarik")
    var dt: Data_DayaTarik2
    databaseReference!!.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener {
        var dtList: ArrayList<Data_DayaTarik2?> = ArrayList<Data_DayaTarik2?>()
        override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
            dtaList.clear()
            for (postSnapshot in snapshot.children) {
                val dt: Data_DayaTarik2? = postSnapshot.getValue(Data_DayaTarik2::class.java)
                dtList.add(dt)
            }
            Collections.sort(dtList) { s1, s2 -> String.valueOf(s1!!.nama_dayatarik).compareTo(s2!!.nama_dayatarik) }
            dataAdapter = MyCustomAdapter(this@PendukungKeputusan_DayaTarik, R.layout.list_dayatarik, dtList)
            val listView = findViewById<ListView>(R.id.list_dayatarik)
            listView.adapter = dataAdapter // set listview dengan dataadapter
           // dataAdapter!!.notifyDataSetChanged();
            searchview_spk.setOnQueryTextListener(object :SearchView.OnQueryTextListener{
                override fun onQueryTextSubmit(query: kotlin.String?): Boolean {
                    //searchview_spk.clearFocus()
                    if(dtList.contains(query)){
                        dataAdapter!!.filter.filter(query)
                    }else{
                        Toast.makeText(applicationContext,"Maaf daya tarik yang anda cari belum ada",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    }
                    return false
                }
                override fun onQueryTextChange(newText: kotlin.String?): Boolean {
                    dataAdapter!!.filter.filter(newText)
                    return false
                }
            })
        }

        override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {}
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(dtList.contains(query)){
    dataAdapter!!.filter.filter(query)
}else{
    Toast.makeText(applicationContext,"Maaf daya tarik yang anda cari belum ada",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
}
```

Here lies your problem, you are checking if

> dtList.contains(query)

where, **"dtList"** contains items of type **"Data_DayaTarik2"** and you are trying to match that with **"query"** which is of type **"String"**.

Hence, the condition is always false and it will never go inside if block and filter the list.

Comment: Thanks, I've upvote to you. but how to handle it ? Data_Dayatarik2 is a model for retrieving data from firebase

Comment: Yes, but on which field you want to apply your search. For eg. Name or Email etc. Also please display what does your model class contain.